# Class name repeated in css file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors

In a .css file i found the code

```
.row { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }

.row .row { margin-top: 0.8em;  margin-bottom: 0; }
```

The html has the code

```
<div class="row">  <div class="col-md-1"> <p>.col-md-1</p> </div> </div>
```

What is the purpose/meaning of the css starting with .row .row?

In the entire code, there is no div with class row within another div with class row. Does that mean that the .row .row will never be used?

Comment: _"In the entire code, there is no div with class row within another div with class row. Does that mean that the .row .row will never be used?"_ Yup.

Comment: Are you sure it said `.row .row` and not `.row.row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the result here: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3mq19j1/)

Only the inner `.row` element of the parent `.row` will be affected by this.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="row"> test </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"> 
        <p>.col-md-1</p> 
    </div> 
</div>


.row { margin-bottom: 1.5em; background:rgba(0,0,0,1); color:#fff;}

.row .row { margin-top: 0.8em;  margin-bottom: 0; background:rgba(0,250,0,1); }
```

Answer (score 2):

With no comma between them, that means an element with the class `row`, that is contained within another element with class `row`.

Answer (score 2):

.row .row select the inner .row of parent .row:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="row">This will be selected</div>
   <div>
      <p class="row">This will also be selected</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So any child element of the row class that has row class will be selected.